# TFS Reporting and SQL Server 2008 Developer

Tags: sql-server, tfs, ssas

I have a TFS 2010 beta 2 installation on a server 2008 r2, with a full instalation of sql server 2008 developer with SP1.

I want to enable the reporting capabilities of TFS, but i can't get to connect TFS with analysis services. The app Tier - Reporting - Edit Dialog keeps me saying that the analysis server cannot be reached. I have only one instance of SQL developer (upgraded from express but with everything installed).

I don't know what to do.... Thanks if somebody can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes this error comes up due to access permissions. Analysis services requires for the most part that you use Windows Authentication to connect to it, so make sure that the user that is trying to connect to analysis services has access to it. The easiest way to verify this is to try and connect using SSMS while logged in as the account that you will use to access Analysis Services.

Comment: OK, I'll do, but when TFS ask me for the AS instance, should i write the same one as the DB engine?

Comment: Yes, if that's where you've installed AS. AS doesn't get installed by default so make sure you've installed it. There should be a service in the service manager if you did. Check that it's running as well.

Comment: Everything is running, but I can't connect to AS neither from TFS or SSMS... what I've did wrong?? I have installed everything (regarless of best practices) under the same user, the windows default administrator.... I'm so confused....

Comment: Are you trying to connect from the same box that has SSAS installed? Are you using the admin account to connect to it? SSAS listens on port 2383 by default. In a command prompt type netstat -a and see if something is listening on port 2383. If it is, then it might be an issue with the user that you are using.